# Exercise from the book Python CRASH COURSE: Exercise 18-2

Tags: python, django-admin

The chapter on the subject doesn't provide an example of how to do it. I'm hoping that someone can deduce it based off of what I've provided or maybe get lucky and someone has read the book who can help.

Here is the exerpt: "Exercise 18-2. Short Entries: The `__str__`() method in the Entry model currently appends an ellipsis to every instance of Entry when Django shows it in the admin site or the shell. Add an `if` statement to the `__str__()` method that adds an ellipsis only if the entry is more than 50 characters long. Use the admin site to add an entry that’s fewer than 50 characters in length, and check that it doesn’t have an ellipsis when viewed."

The block of code is at the bottom:

```
from django.db import models

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the definition of `__str__()` is straightforward :

```
from django.db import models

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text[:50] + ("..." if len(self.text) > 50 else "")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.db import models

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        if len(self.text) > 50:
            return f"{self.text[:50]}..."
        else:
            return f"{self.text}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db import models

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        if len(self.text) < 50:
            return self.text
        else:
            return self.text[:50]
```